# Give the number of words in 32 bit main memory

Tags: memory, computer-science, cpu-architecture

A computer’s main memory is word addressable. Addresses referencing the words in main memory each have 32 bits. Give the number of words in main memory in terms of GiBs

I am a little confused with the question above. Given that the word is 2^n = 2^32 which is 4 bytes.

Comment: Start by ensuring you understand what all the terms used mean. For instance, what **exactly** does it mean that the memory is word addressable? Also, did the problem state that words are 32-bit, or did you infer this from the address size?

Comment: Thanks for your response @LasseV.Karlsen The question states that addresses referencing the words in main memory each have 32 bits

Comment: That tells you the address size, from which you can calculate the number of unique addresses.  It tells you nothing about how big each word is that you'll find at that address.

Comment: Oh I see! This means the information is not enough to determine the number of words